# Creating a function that counts matches in 2 arrays. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, boolean

I am trying to create a function that grades student papers and returns a score. To do this I have attempted adding a loop to the function that compares studentAnswers with teachersCopy.length and added an empty variable, score= 0. I want the score to increase by 1 every time studentAnswers[i]===teachersCopy[i]. I tried using a Boolean but I can't get it right, here's what I got:

```
function gradeQuiz(studentAnswers, teacherAnswers)
{
  let score= 0
  for (let i=0; i<teacherAnswers.length; i++)
    if (studentAnswers[i]==teachersAnswers[i])
    {
      score= ++
    }
    return score
}
gradeQuiz(['C', 'D', 'B'],['C', 'A', 'B'])
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use curly braces for the ```for loop```

Comment: Also `score++` instead of `score= ++`

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few syntax errors here:

```
function gradeQuiz(studentAnswers, teacherAnswers){
  let score = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<teacherAnswers.length; i++){    // include open brace
    if (studentAnswers[i] == teacherAnswers[i]){  // typo, should be "teacherAnswers"
      score ++;                                   // =++ should just be ++
    }
   }                                              // close brace
   return score;
}
gradeQuiz(['C', 'D', 'B'],['C', 'A', 'B']);
```

In the future, try looking in your browser's console. Errors like missing braces or typos in variable names should be easy to spot using console error messages.

Comment: `return score` must be outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are  several errors in your code.

1. `score++` was not written in proper way.
2. `teachersAnswers` was misspelled.

You can check my solution.

```js
function gradeQuiz(studentAnswers, teacherAnswers)
{
  let score= 0
  for (let i=0; i<teacherAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (studentAnswers[i] === teacherAnswers[i])
    {
      score++
    }
  }
  return score
}
console.log(gradeQuiz(['C', 'D', 'B'],['C', 'A', 'B']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Sajeeb's comment, do score++ instead of score = ++(it isn't a valid expression). If you want, you can also do score += 1. Also, the parameter is teacherAnswers  and you wrote teachersAnswers. Like

```
    function gradeQuiz(studentAnswers, teacherAnswers)
    {
       var score= 0
       for (let i=0; i<teacherAnswers.length; i++) {
         if (studentAnswers[i]==teacherAnswers[i])
        {
          score++
        }
    }
         return score
   }

    console.log(gradeQuiz(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Hope I've helped!